# Iframe is not displayed on Android devices in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, iframe

You see, I have the following situation, I have an Iframe that is displayed on apple devices without problem, no matter the model, in desktop / pc it is displayed without problem, on android devices with any browser other than chrome is displayed correctly, now, with Android devices and chrome browser sometimes shows the IFrame and other times not, my IFrame is the following:

```
<iframe id="lgnIfra" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" onLoad="resize()" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="<%=path%>" align="bottom" iframe.src="javascript:parent.getFrameHTML()"></iframe>
```

Is there any way to load IFrame without any problem on Android devices and using chrome as a browser?

Update 1

I get next error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
```

This is my line in file .js

```
iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Any solution?

Comment: Try using some height value, percent or fixed, to see what happens.

Comment: @statosdotcom update my question